# How to solve diophantine equation $2a(a+d)=(c-d)(c+d)$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Solve diophantine equation
$2a(a+d)=(c-d)(c+d)$

given $1 \le a < c$ and $1 \le d$

Also Lets say I have the value of $d$ known , how should I express $a$ as a function of it.i.e. $a=f(d)$ ?

**My thoughts so far:**

$(c-d)$ and $(c+d)$ are integers $2d$ distance apart.To satisfy $2d$ distance condition if one is even other is too and similarly if one is odd other is too.
But to satisfy LHS having $2$ both $(c-d)$ and $(c+d)$ can not be odd so both must be even.
Let $c-d=2k$, then the equation becomes $$2a(a+d)=2k(2k+2d) \implies a(a+d)=2k(k+d)$$
now we have product of two number who are $d$ distance apart on both LHS and RHS but one is twice the other.

Comment: What happened to $b$ in the equation? Was it originally $(a+b)(a+d)=(c-d)(c+d)$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde no it was't. You can rename variables to whatever you like for your convenience.

Comment: Yes, sure. But it looked suspicious, that $b$ was missing :) What is the source of this equation?

Comment: @DietrichBurde souce is tiny excerpt from my other research works, so all variable names are created by me. they are not from any text book, let me name it sequentially if thats bothering you.

Comment: For $a=1$ we obtain $c^2-(d+1)^2=1$, which is a Pell equation.

Answer (score 4):

I guess the best approach is to use the Pythagorean triple as below:

$$2a(a+d)=(c-d)(c+d)\implies d^2+2ad+2a^2=(d+a)^2+a^2=c^2;$$

hence the solutions should be:
$$a+d=k(m^2-n^2),$$
$$a=k(2mn),$$
$$c=k(m^2+n^2),$$

where $k,m,n$ are integers. Moreover, it should be added that in order to meet the conditions of the problem, $m,n,k$ should be chosen in a particular way; however the general form of the answer is the same.

[This link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) is helpful, I think.

---

---

**Another situation when $d$ is given;**

If $d$ is a constant value, then we should look for $m,n$ such that $m^2-n^2-2mn=d$, hence:

$$m=\frac{2n\pm \sqrt {4n^2+4n^2+4d}}{2}=n\pm \sqrt {2n^2+d}.$$

In this case, according to the given $d$ we just need to look for some $n$ such that $\sqrt {2n^2+d}$ is a square, and this is entirely another problem.

Comment: Lets say I have value of d known , how many values of m and n should I test to get $a$ ? can you add some thoughts to this. I have updated the question,

Comment: @rosefoster I also updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks . Let me create a separate problem to solve the last part. My hunch says we might not need more than  $\sqrt{d}$ values of $n$ to get the first square. and there must also be some periodicity in $n$ to jump from the first square to the next square. Basically I am down to finding the series of the $n$. But you are right it should be a separate question.

Comment: @dietrich-burde was right. it turns out to be a form of [generalized pells](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4562952/1057393)