# Given $d$, how many values of $n$ should I test to get a square of form ${2n^2+d}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pell-type-equations

Given $d$, how many values of $n$ should I test to get a square of the form ${2n^2+d}$

Both $d$ and $n$ are a positive integers.

There must also be some periodicity in $n$ to jump from the first square to the second square and so on. Basically I am looking to find that series of $n$ for which ${2n^2+d}$ is a square.

My testing so far has shown that for some values of $d$ there is no $n$ at all which can generate a square.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Generalized Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#Generalized_Pell's_equation).

Comment: Indeed, this is equivalent to finding solutions to the generalized Pell equation $X^2 - 2Y^2 = d$. This can be solved explicitly using continued fractions and solutions to the standard Pell equation $X^2 - 2Y^2 = 1$. I know how to carry this out. If no one answers this before I do, I'll return and write this out later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding squares of the form $2n^2 + d$ is equivalent to finding solutions to the generalized Pell equation
$$ X^2 - 2Y^2 = d. \tag{1}$$
We call this *generalized* Pell equation because there is a $d$ instead of $1$. The typical Pell equation is
$$ X^2 - 2Y^2 = 1. \tag{2}$$

The philosophy with this sort of question is that if $(x_0, y_0)$ is a solution to the standard Pell equation $(2)$, and $(x_j, y_j)$ is a solution to the generalized Pell equation $(1)$, then the coefficients $(A, B)$, defined by
$$A + B\sqrt{y} := (x_0 + y_0 \sqrt{2})(x_j + y_j \sqrt{2}),$$
give another solution. This is actually straightforward to show explicitly, or by noting that $(x_0, y_0)$ is a solution to $(2)$ exactly when the $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ norm $N(x_0 + y_0 \sqrt{2}) = 1$. Similarly, $(x_j, y_j)$ is a solution to $(2)$ when $N(x_j + y_j \sqrt{2}) = d$. And norms are multiplicative, proving the statement about $(A, B)$.

Typical Pell methods of continued fractions give all solutions to $(2)$. There is a single fundamental solution (which I now take as $(x_0, y_0)$) such that every other solution is of the form $(x_0 + y_0 \sqrt{2})^k$. Here, that fundamental solution is $(3, 2)$.

The other part is $(x_j, y_j)$. One can show that there is a finite (possibly zero) $J$ and a finite list (possibly empty) of solutions $(x_j, y_j)$ with $0 \leq j \leq J$ such that *every* solution to $(2)$ is of the form
$$ (3 + 2 \sqrt{2})^k(x_j + y_j \sqrt{2}). \qquad (0 \leq j \leq J, k \geq 1)$$
Details are written in Andreescu's book *Quadratic Diophantine Equations*.

Write $u = 3 + 2 \sqrt{2}$, the fundamental solution to the normal Pell equation. One can show that each of the initial solutions $(x_j, y_j)$ satisfy
$$ \lvert x_j \rvert \leq \frac{\sqrt{d}(\sqrt{u} + 1)}{2}, \quad
\lvert y_j \rvert \leq \frac{\sqrt{d}(\sqrt{u} + 1)}{2 \sqrt{2}} .$$
Proving this is annoying.

This brings the task to a finite computation. We have the fundamental solution $(3, 2)$ to $(2)$. For any given $d$, one can check all potential solutions up to the bound above, and this gives all solutions.

But there is one last piece: it is possible to determine when there are no solutions without much work. This is described in [the other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4563342/9754).

Let's do a concrete example with $d = 9$. Computation shows that the generating solutions will satisfy $\lvert x_j \rvert \leq 10$ and $\lvert y_j \rvert \leq 7$. Explicitly checking shows the solutions
$$(\pm 9, \pm 6), (\pm 3, 0). $$
Thus we have found **all** solutions when $d = 9$.

For concreteness, we explore this example a bit more.
One nonobvious infinite family of solutions then come from
$$ (3 + 2 \sqrt{2})^k(9 + 6 \sqrt{2}). $$
The first several solutions of this form are

$$
36\sqrt{2} + 51,
210\sqrt{2} + 297,
1224\sqrt{2} + 1731,
7134\sqrt{2} + 10089,
$$
$$
41580\sqrt{2} + 58803,
242346\sqrt{2} + 342729,
1412496\sqrt{2} + 1997571,
$$
$$
8232630\sqrt{2} + 11642697,
47983284\sqrt{2} + 67858611,
279667074\sqrt{2} + 395508969.
$$
For example, we can check that
$$ 395508969^2 - 2 \cdot 279667074^2 = 9. $$

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for solutions $(m, n)$ to the equation $m^2 - 2n^2 = d$. As indicated in the comments, these are known as Pell's equations. Basically, knowing one solution would allow you to easily generate the sequence of all solutions.

On the other hand, the question of whether there exist solutions for certain $d$, is equivalent to asking whether $d$ is a norm in the field extension $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)/\Bbb Q$. The result is given by quadratic reciprocity.

More precisely, if you write $|d| = \prod_{i = 1}^r p_i^{e_i}$, then there exists $n$ such that $2n^2 + d$ is a square if and only if for each $p_i$ that is congruent to $3, 5$ mod $8$, the exponent $e_i$ is even.

This is because the integer ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ has class number $1$, hence every split prime is a norm.

For a good presentation of the details, e.g. the book *Primes of the form $x^2 + ny^2$* by D. Cox is a good reference.